# How to insert Double[] into HBase?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

For Example,
if i want to insert a double[] like,
Double[] dArr={10.23,25.1,30.5,45.3};
into HBase table.
Could you plzz tell me how to insert it into hbase??

Answer (score 1):

You can store anything you want, you just have to serialize it to a byte[]:

```
Double[] dArr={10.23,25.1,30.5,45.3};
byte[] value = new byte[0];
byte[] family = "f".getBytes();
byte[] column = "d".getBytes();
for (Double d:dArr) {
    value = Bytes.add(value, Bytes.toBytes(d));
}
Put put = new Put( rowKey );
put.add(family, column, Bytes.toBytes(value));
...
```

You'll have to unserialize the data when you read the value (convert from byte[] to Double[])

Another thing you can do is store each Double (as byte[]) in its own column (d0 to dX)

```
Double[] dArr={10.23,25.1,30.5,45.3};
Put put = new Put( rowKey );
byte[] family = "f".getBytes();
byte[] column = "d".getBytes();
int i=0;
for (Double d:dArr) {
    put.add( family, Bytes.add(column, Bytes.toBytes(i)), Bytes.toBytes(d));
    i++;
}
...
```